# What are the language and product alternatives to Akka?

Tags: playframework, rabbitmq, akka, actor

Right now I'm looking at [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) and like it a lot. One of the parts heavy advertised amongst the features offered in Play is [Akka](http://akka.io/).

In order to better understand Akka and how to use it properly, can you tell me what are the alternatives in other languages or products?

How does [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) compare to it? Is there a lot of overlap? Is it practical using them together? IN what use cases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best place to start is a [great Akka official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/). I think the closest product/framework to Akka is [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) language. I *guess* (I haven't used Play framework) Akka is used there to implement Comet and other asynchronous processing.

[rabbitmq](/questions/tagged/rabbitmq) is somewhat similar in ideas (infrastructure for sending messages), note that RabbitMQ is even written in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang), but they have slightly different use-cases. I would say that while RabbitMQ focuses on message passing, Akka is more about actors (message receivers and senders).

Comment: RabbitMQ is an AMQP broker, i.e. a transport. Akka is a concurrency/scalability/fault-tolerance toolkit. You can use AMQP as Akka Actor mailboxes or as Akka remoting transport.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,just to clerify, if I have multiple java applicatons, i want them to communicate, i will need rabbitmq.  For example 2 seperate play 2 apps, seperate machines, akka can't be the joining framework, i will need jms or rabbitmq, is this correct?

Comment: You can “join” JVMs using remote actors, they come with a default transport which is based on Netty.

Comment: @ViktorKlang using AMQP as a durable mailbox doesn't feel right. AMQP shines in a pubsub/messaging scenario, whereas for a durable mailbox I'd rather consider a dedicated store of some sort (Redis, filesystem, etc)

Answer (score 21):

I use [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) + Spring AMQP + Guava's EventBus to automatically register Actor-like messengers using [Guava's EventBus for pattern matching](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) the received messages.

The similarity to Spring AMQP and Akka is uncanny. Spring AMQP's [SimpleMessageListenerContainer + MessageListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/#d0e402)  is pretty much equivalent to an Actor.

However for all intents and purposes RabbitMQ is more *powerful* than Akka in that it has many client **implementations** in different languages, **provides persistence** (durable queues), **topological routing** and **pluggable QoS algorithms**.

That being said Akka is way more convenient and in theory Akka can do all of the above and some people have written extensions but most just use Akka and then have Akka deliver the messages over RabbitMQ. Also Spring AMQP SimpleMessageListener container is kind of heavy and its unclear what would happen if you created a couple of million of them.

**In hindsight I would consider using Akka to RabbbitMQ instead of Spring AMQP for future projects.**

Comment: Akka supports durable mailboxes which are similar to the persistent queues that RabbitMQ provides.

Comment: Yes I found that out recently.  My main beef with Akka is that if your using Java to interface with it you seem to have to do a lot of casting. The other thing is there are amqp clients in other languages like python.

Comment: According to http://letitcrash.com/post/29988753572/akka-amqp-proxies, Akka can use AMQP as a transport.  AMQP is a standard wire-level protocol so doesn't preclude Akka or any programming language or operating environment from using it as a transport to communicate with clients written in other programming languages.

Comment: Yes that is right just like I noted In my answer there are extensions for Akka. Still you need some on top of Akka to talk to other technologies. There are couple of other issues with Akka in that you have to be very mindful of threadlocals.

Answer (score 11):

The best advice I can offer, as I also went through the same thought process when Play 2.0 joined Typesafe and started to use Akka more, is to search for "Actor model".

Wikipedia is a great resource - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model. It has a list of programming languages that can support the actor model, and also has a list of frameworks (including Akka) that are based on the Actor model.

Put simply, the Actor model is based around the concept of actors in a concurrent computation model. Actors doesn't necessarily mean passing of messages, but most common use cases will have actors passing messages (which is where the similarities with rabbitMQ will come in).

Comment: Small correction with large impact: actors can ONLY be passed messages, that is the essence of the concept. Actors are a model of computation while rabbitMQ is a means to pass messages, hence they live on different levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

You can also consider use Vertx, which is also a Reactive platform http://vertx.io/

Where there you can consider the Verticle(http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles) similar to Actor paradigm.
And the EventBus similar as Databus of Akka(http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus)

Answer (score 3):

Akka is a toolkit and runtime for building **concurrent** & **distributed** systems. To achieve this, Akka use Actor model. If you are looking for an alternative for Akka, i think you can not find a complete solution like Akka, because Akka have several features that enable you to develop robust **concurrent** & **distributed** system:

- Akka actor
- Actor Routing, Supervising and Monitoring
- Asynchronous and non-blocking messaging
- Akka Cluster (for cluster management)
- Akka persistence (for implementing Event sourcing, persistence actor and At-Least-Once Delivery messaging)
- Akka I/O (for TCP & UDP communication)
- Akka HTTP (for HTTP communication as client or server)
- Akka Stream (for stream processing)
- ...

But i suggest to take a look at [Erlang/OTP](https://www.erlang.org/) and [Quasar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/).

Comment: As for a comparison with Quasar, I also suggest to take a look at http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2015/05/21/quasar-vs-akka/. Note that Galaxy is not yet production-ready (it'll be soon though) but on the other hand Quasar Actors are so similar to Erlang's (and thus so straightforward) that integrating with practically any messaging solution is extremely easy and we'll soon write more about that.

DISCLAIMER: I'm part of the Quasar team.

Answer (score 1):

http://scalecube.io is a low latency microservices lib .
a complete solution that enable you to develop robust concurrent & distributed system.

Like Akka:
- its based on gossip and swim protocol.
- its message driven based on protobuf (full duplex). 
- its for the JVM.
- low latency and about ~6 times faster.
- uses RxJava proven to be faster than akka streams.

Unlike Akka:
- its less opinionated
- not a framework.
- not forcing Actor pattern as holistic pattern.

Comment: It seems that it hasn't got anything for persistance. Maybe, different beast?