# AKKA and other messaging systems

Tags: akka, amqp, hornetq

I have red [Good use case for Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka)

For short: Akka provides or is nothing more than a "messaging system". Am I right?

**1. How does AKKA compare to other messaging systems, such as AMQP, RabbitMQ or HornetQ ?**

**2. Why should I use AKKA instead of a (real) messaging system such as HornetQ ?**

Comment: I have red http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648280/scala-actors-vs-jms/4648843, which clarifies the concepts of both.

Answer (score 3):

1. Akka is a toolkit for concurrency, fault-tolerance and distribution. A Message Broker brokes messages.
2. Define "real". Assuming you're talking about Akka Actors, an Akka Actor can process about 3 million messages per second on a normal box, and you can have about 2.7 million Actors per gigabyte of heap.

In general I think you might want to read up a bit on the Actor Model of computation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Comment: Thanks! As stated in http://www.jboss.org/hornetq, hornetq can process "8.2 Millions Messages per second with SpecJMS".

Comment: Okay, I will digg into the documentation of AKKA to look if I can use it instead of HornetQ.

Comment: Yes, but those stats are for the entire HornetQ server, my stats were per Actor. We do >50 million messages per second in total on our test rig: http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single-machine

Comment: Wow. That is really great. I really cannot say why to use HornetQ instead of AKKA. I will give it a try.

Comment: As I alluded to earlier, you're really comparing apples to pears. I cannot tell you what you should use, you should choose what suits your use-case.

Comment: I am actually using HornetQ and I have to read the docs of AKKA to know the real difference between those (I am actually doing this;). I know, against AKKA HornetQ is a MessageBroker, which also provides concurrency, fault-tolerance and distribution. There are other message brokers which uses the engine of Akka (AKKA-AMQP). (I am wondering if HornetQ were much faster, when using AKKA as its engine) But as I said before, I will read the docs of AKKA to better my picture. Thanks.